# IfElse nested not working

Tags: netlogo

please check this code. which part is wrong

```
to catch-lizards
    let prey one-of lizards-here
    ifelse prey = "lizard2"
    [ show "WRONG" ask prey [die]
     set lifetime = lifetime + hawks-life-gain ]
    [ifelse droping-tail? = true
    [ask prey [set shape "lizard2"
    set lifetime lifetime + hawks-life-gain / 4 ] ]
    [ask prey [die]
    set lifetime lifetime + hawks-life-gain ]
   ]
  ]
end
```

problem is in place where (show "wrong") is written. that part doesn't execute. is syntax not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ifelse prey = "lizard2"` part, you compare whether the `prey` *is* the string `lizard2`. But the prey is not a string, it is an object having some properties, like `shape` or `lifetime`.

So you need to ask whether *the shape of the prey* is `lizard2`.

**Update:** Checking the shape of the prey probably looks like this:

```
ask prey [
  ifelse shape = "lizard2" [
    …
  ] [
    …
  ]
]
```

Comment: i want to check if PREY shape is LIZARD2 . thats the condition. how do i do that? PREY is agentset and LIZARD1, LIZARD2 are its shapes. i want to interchange these shapes under some conditions.